# Set more-than-one keyword option as selected by default?

Tags: 2011, schema, content-modeling

My customer wants to add keywords to an existing Category, which is used in an existing schema. Keywords **`A`**, **`B`**, and **`C`** already exist and have been selected in various components. Customer is considering new keywords **`D`** and **`E`**.

**Requirement**: add additional "options" while minimizing authoring steps. The new selections could be one of either **`D`**, **`E`**, or *both*.  **Can multiple keywords be selected by default for authors (in new and existing components)?**

**Setup:**

- **`A`**, **`B`**, and **`C`** are already selected in a few thousand components. None have **`D`** or **`E`** selected.
- Fields published to storage (broker) and queried by CD API.

The existing multimedia components should have **`D`** and **`E`** checked as well, but won't by default.

**Edit**: removed options to make question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address the issue of existing content only: You can run an advanced search in the CME GUI, on the root of the Content publication, using Based On Schema to find all existing components using the schema in question. Then simply right click and select Classification-->Classify to add the keywords D and E to all existing components.

Comment: As a "schema change" my mind automatically went to component *synchronization*. :-) +1 and accepted as a great solution for this scenario. Basically the team would add the new checkbox options in a way that made sense to authors and then do *some* manual work to classify old content. SHIFT-click and CTRL+A could also help selecting multiple items in desired folders.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there's no ootb, default way to join the two fields together say for example in your first drop down you select 'Country', then your second 'City' would validate that the information makes sense.

It's possible to have related keywords in the CMS, so the data could be stored with these relation, but there's no way to work with this in the GUI at the user point of view.

You've noted a number of ways to do the development of this, I think the best bet would be via the event system in that you could validate if your second keyword.

Hope I've answered your Q here Alvin, or given you enough to figure it out.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer. This wasn't so much a validation scenario as wanting multiple checkboxes selected by default. My main point is for the developer to consider existing content and maybe adjust the approach (especially if mixing checkboxes with a new "radio button" option). So it's probably a good idea to add a new schema field at the minimum.

Comment: Wait, we can display keyword relationships with the tree option and nested keywords. So if the new items are related in this way, we could get away with a single nested option (if selecting `E` implied `D` for example). +1 for mentioning the event system.